# iis7.5 many-to-one client certificate mapping causes error status 500

Tags: iis-7.5, client-certificates

We are trying to implement client certificate authentication in IIS 7.5. We have configured many-to-one mapping, disabled all other authentication modes and now the cert-authentication seems to work correctly: we can correctly read the certificate information from a test .aspx page and also the authenticated username is the one configured in many-to-one mappings.

However, even though everything *seems* to work correctly, each "new" browser session causes one "extra" error status 500 row in the IIS log, just before the authentication is successful:

```
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port ... cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2013-02-12 09:46:35 10.40.64.45 GET /certtest.aspx - 443 - ... - site.mydomain.com 500 0 64 31
2013-02-12 09:46:35 10.40.64.45 GET /certtest.aspx - 443 - ... - site.mydomain.com 200 0 0 734
```

Same "extra" error status 500 issue happens for any file, e.g. for images, .css, .js, so certainly it's not a problem in the certtest.aspx file.

Any ideas, what could cause this error status 500 in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we managed to solve this issue by setting the SSLAlwaysNegoClientCert Metabase Property to True.

[Technet article from IIS6.0 (!) Admin reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778630%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)